# a program to change letters in DNA nucleotide

Tags: python

I'm making a program to change the sequence of DNA. When finding the letter "a", replace it with a "t", and opposite. But I've encountered a problem cause when the program runs, it replaces "a" with "t", then replaces "t" with "a" again.

How can I fix that?

The code:

```
def opposite_nucleotide(dna):
     dna = dna.replace("a", "t")
     dna = dna.replace("t", "a")
     dna = dna.replace("g", "c")
     dna = dna.replace("c", "g")
     return dna

dna3 = input("Enter the DNA to represent it's oppsite one: ")
dna4 = opposite_nucleotide(dna3)
print(dna4)
```

Comment: maybe store the locations of 'a' , 't', 'g', 'c' and then replace all locations of 'a' with 't' and all locations of 't' with 'a' and do the same with 'g' and 'c'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 def opposite_nucleotide(dna):
     new_dna = ""
     for char in dna:
         if char == "a":
             new_dna += "t"
         elif char == "t":
             new_dna += "a"
         elif char == "g":
             new_dna += "c"
         else:
             new_dna += "g"
     return new_dna
```

I guess this should work.. not pretty but should work

Comment: This worked and inspired me with a new idea! Thanks

Answer (score 9):

As it turns out, this functionality is [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) in Python.

> str.translate(table)
>
> Return a copy of the string in which each character has been mapped through the given translation table. ...
>
> You can use str.maketrans() to create a translation map from character-to-character mappings in different formats.

Example usage:

```
def opposite_nucleotide(dna):
    return dna.translate(str.maketrans("atgc", "tacg"))
```

[`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) can be called several ways, but the form I use above is similar to how you would use `tr//` in Perl: each character in the first argument will be replaced by the corresponding character in the second.

Obviously, if you're doing this for coursework or educational purposes, don't just appeal to a built-in.

Comment: Nice find! Didn't know about the translate-related possibilities in Python.

Comment: nerver knew this ever exists

Answer (score 2):

#this won't work well for large DNA strings

```
m=dict(zip('atgc','tacg'))
dna4=''.join([m[c] for c in dna3])
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest modification to your code to do this (though likely not the most efficient), would be to use temporary replacements, which are characters known to be missing from the string.  By replacing "a" with "x", for example, then replacing "t" with "a", and finally "x" with "t", you will not replace letters which have already been replaced.

```
def opposite_nucleotide(dna):
     dna = dna.replace("a", "x")
     dna = dna.replace("t", "a")
     dna = dna.replace("x", "t")
     dna = dna.replace("g", "y")
     dna = dna.replace("c", "g")
     dna = dna.replace("y", "c")
     return dna

dna3 = input("Enter the DNA to represent it's oppsite one: ")
dna4 = opposite_nucleotide(dna3)
print(dna4)
```

Comment: This worked too and it's a great idea but in things like this which doesn't have many letters but it's great Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Would an approach like this work?

```
def opp(string):
    result = []
    for char in string:
        if char == 'a':
            result.append('t')
        elif char == 't':
            result.append('a')
        elif char == 'g':
            result.append('c')
        elif char == 'c':
            result.append('g')
    return ''.join(result)

print(opp('atgc'))
```

**Output:**

```
tacg
```

Thanks @bullseye for the idea; I changed the extra `if` statements to `elif` for now!

Comment: you forgot the `else` block ... `else: result.append(char)`

Comment: @bullseye If there are only four items that need to be checked (in this case related to DNA), I don't know if there is a need for an extra `else` in this example, but maybe I'm not seeing it? I don't know of other characters that would need to be added in this case to the DNA string. But if there are, adding an `else` like your example should preserve the extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

what is the input file format? is it a fasta file ? do you want the program to just replace all the strings in the file with t  to a and vice versa? or just replace only the string you enter?